# How can weight of an body $=$ weight of displaced liquid by the body?

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics

> Weight of an body $=$ Weight of displaced liquid by the body

If this is true, then according to Archimedes law, which says that,

> Buoyant force $=$ Weight of the liquid displaced by the body

Will imply that the apparent weight of body will always be zero.

As the weight of a body will equal to the apparent weight (if the above is true).

Please help!
I think I am misunderstanding the law and above principle so please help!

Comment: Are you talking about a body completely immersed in liquid (like a stone or a submarine) or partially immersed in liquid (like a boat)?

Comment: Your statement only applies to floating objects.

Answer (score 2):

"weight of an body = weight of displaced liquid by the body."

This is not a general law. It is the condition that a body *float*, the so-called *principle of flotation*.

It follows from Archimedes' principle, which IS a general law: The weight of displaced fluid equals the resultant upward force from the fluid on the body.

Comment: But it may depend like how much part of body is inside water (1/3). I saw an answer from Internet that it’s showing 2/3 rd of body is inside water. If 1/2 of body was inside water than I would understand

Comment: If you place a body (a piece of wood, say) on the surface of the liquid, the weight of the body (that is the pull of gravity on it) will pull it downwards. The deeper it sinks (assuming that it is not fully immersed) the more liquid it displaces and the greater the upthrust that the surrounding liquid exerts on it. When upthrust = weight we have equilibrium (floating). This can occur for any fraction submerged depending on the densities of body and liquid: a homogeneous body whose density is 2/3 that of the liquid will be in equilibrium with 2/3 of its volume submerged – and so on.

Comment: The condition for equilibrium is $$\text{Upthrust} = \text{Weight of body}$$ So $$\text{Weight of liquid displaced} = \text{Weight of body}$$ So $$V_{\text{liq disp}}\  \rho_{\text{liq}}\ g=V_{\text{body}}\  \rho_{\text{body}}\ g$$ So $$\frac{V_{\text{liq disp}}}{V_{\text{body}}}=\frac{\rho_{\text {body}}}{\rho_{\text{liq}}}$$

Comment: Is it that if a object is submerged 2/3 inside the liquid then:- weight of 2/3 of the volume of liquid displaced is the force needed to keep 1/3th part of body outside the liquid ?

Comment: No. I don't think that the weight of 2/3 of the volume of liquid displaced has any significance. The weight of the total volume displaced is what matters. Have you followed the argument that I have given in my comments?

Answer (score 1):

Archimedes' principle is always true. The observation "the apparent weight of body will always be zero" is also true unless the body sinks (because the weight of the body is larger than that of the displaced liquid), in which case there is obviously a non-zero "apparent weight".

Answer (score 1):

This statement in your question

"buoyant force = weight of the liquid displaced by the body, will imply that the apparent weight of body will always be zero"

has two parts.

This part is true

"buoyant force = weight of the liquid displaced by the body"

but "will imply that the apparent weight of body will always be zero" is false.

If the body is dense and sinks to the bottom of the container, there can still be an 'apparent weight' pulling down on the body (that's balanced by a reaction force from the bottom of the container).

Comment: But it may depend like how much part of body is inside water (1/3). I saw an answer from Internet that it’s showing 2/3 rd of body is inside water. If 1/2 of body was inside water than I would understand.

Comment: Buoyancy force is always equal to the weight of the fluid displaced.  If it's a object of low density, it doesn't need to have much of it inside the water to create the necessary buoyancy force to balance the weight.  If it's high density, the first sentence is still true, but the buoyancy force is not enough to balance the weight and it sinks.

Comment: Is it that if a object is submerged 2/3 inside the liquid then:- weight of 2/3 of the volume of liquid displaced is the force needed to keep 1/3th part of body outside the liquid ?

Comment: @  Please answer If the volume of the object is $V$ and density of the liquid $\rho_{liq}$ and density of object $\rho_{obj}$ , since upthrust equals weight of fluid displaced and must also match the weight of the object, then $\frac{2}{3}\rho_{liq}Vg = \rho_{obj}Vg$.  Perhaps the term 'displaced' is causing confusion, if so see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(fluid).  All the best

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Archimedes' Principle is correct.

**Yes**, Apparent weight of a **floating object** is zero. Because $$\text{apparent weight=real weight - upthrust} $$ But every object is not floating. Thus this is not always correct (zero apparent weight). A heavy ball submerged in the water hanging from a Newton balance still have a non-zero apparent weight.

Answer (score 1):

> weight of an body = weight of displaced liquid by the body

Where did you get the above statement from ? That is inaccurate.

The correct statement is

Buoyant force on a body = weight of displaced liquid by the body